# spring-session not insert session in database

Tags: spring, spring-session

I'm use Spring-session to store session in database,  in log executing the querys select and drop for session, but never insert session in tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fwYq.png)

Comment: Please share your code or error in text format not in image format